# How to include javascript from a CDN source using smarty

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, cdn

How do you include Javascript from a CDN source using Smarty?  We have code such as the following for including it from a file on the web server, but I want to include it from a CDN instead.

```
{javascript file="prototype.js" priority=20}
```

When I access the Smarty documentation at http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/ "javascript" cannot be found anywhere within the page, and when I try to search the documentation the results from the following are not at all helpful: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/search.php?query=javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just include the remote `.js` file, using the HTML `<script>` tag ?

Something like that, I suppose :

```
<script 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

*(Well, you can use another CDN than google's of course -- I took that URL as an example)*

I've never heard of that `{javascript}` tag for smarty; maybe it's a plugin that's been defined in your project?

Comment: correct about {javascript} being: "a plugin that's been defined in your project"

Comment: You're missing the closing " for the type attribute in your script tag

Comment: @rmcsharry You don't need to explain why you edited in the edit itself. If the problem is that the edit is less than 6 characters, you can add a `<!---->` somewhere in the body, which will not be visible since it's a comment.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, it was indeed the 6 character issue. Now I know a better way, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

We use the following pattern:

```
<script src="{$page.cdn}prototype.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

Where $page contains information that changes based on the environment.

Development server:

```
$page.cdn = /resources/
```

Production server:

```
$page.cdn = http://cdn.domain.com/app
```